# Copying entire schema from one redshift cluster to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I would like to copy my schema tables structure without the data from one redshift cluster to another cluster so that both clusters have the same structure.

I understand we can use UNLOAD from one Cluster to the S3 bucket and then COPY to another cluster. However, this applies to a table. Does it apply to the schema as well?  I have 262 tables in my current cluster.

Would the UNLOAD and LOAD allow me to copy my schema tables to another cluster?

Answer (score 0):

LOAD and UNLOAD does not define/copy a schema.

Instead, I think you could ([Use Amazon Redshift as a source for AWS Schema Conversion Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Redshift.html). This will 'extract' the schema for a table and give you the SQL DDL commands that can be used to create the table in another Amazon Redshift cluster.